# Why did Killua kill the opponent of Leorio?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I'm currently watching the anime series Hunter x Hunter. I'm currently on the episode 30. But looking back, I get confused why exactly did Killua kill the opponent of Leorio.

Before the fight, his brother was seemingly hypnotizing him that he will need to step back if he know that his opponent is stronger than him, thus making him protecting Killua.

His brother also stated that a certain day will come that Killua will leave Gon to die. I don't get the point why such action will be done to Kill the opponent of Leorio.

Comment: Congratulations OP (hey cool initials), you get the answer straight from the source (Killua not the Mangaka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay, I watched this again yesterday:

1. He felt he had to quit the exam due to pressure from his brother (which involves literal and quite horrific mind control that is explained in more detail in the chimera ants arc).
2. Disqualification is a faster way to quit than waiting to the end.
3. He wanted to kill something as he is quite a blood thirsty individual and wanted to reaffirm his strength and control over the world.
4. He lost most of his self control because of his emotional state.  Note that he truely believed that Illumi would kill Gon and that his losing the match without fighting proved his was not fit to be a normal human. He was not willing to fight to protect his only friend from being killed.

While he might have considered that killing that opponent helped Leoreo that was determined not to be why he did it.  If it was why he killed him, Leoreo would have been disqualified as was explained when Leoreo (and later Killua too) wanted to step in against Hanso to protect Gon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer comes down to two factors:

1. Killua could not just quit the hunter exam at that point
2. By killing the opponent he did, he helped Leorio while also furthering his own goal (i.e. being disqualified)

Comment: It's more like this furthered his brother's goal. Why he would do this for his brother, is another question (which might lead to spoilers).